# php code to attach page in variable and display variable in anchor line

Tags: php

below is my link code

**detail.php is used to show detail of row by using row id.**

**My question is ...Is It Possible to pass complete link in certain variable and and only access this variable except of attaching page on every link.**

**Or Any function where i put my page name detail.php and access this function on link.
plz suggest me....**

for exampl -

$var = detail.php and used this var like below link.

```
 <a href="$var?id=<?php echo $row1['id']; ?>"></a>
```

Not like below link.
">

Comment: an example of what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly but I think this is what you are looking for:

```
$rows; //variable with all database rows
$baseString = "details.php";
foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    $pageString = $baseString . "?id=" . $row['id'];
    ?>
    <h2><a href="<?php echo $pageString; ?>"><?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($row['headline']); ?></a></h2>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: no i need is,to get details.php in variable or any function and pass this variable anchor link except of attaching page.........

Comment: Something like my new edit?